# load a *.xlsb file from Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to load a *.xlsb file from Azure Function App, Is there a tool or solution for this?

Below don't support *.xlsb:

https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-Sdk

Below is not free:

https://www.easyxls.com/manual/basics/convert-xlsb-to-xlsx.html

Any idea?

**Update**

it must be in C#

Comment: I update my answer post and hope it helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

I create a simple `xlsx` file and write some data into it, then to save it as a `xlsb` file. Next, I used [`pyxlsb`](https://pypi.org/project/pyxlsb/) package in Python to read it successfully, as the figure below.

[image]

```
>>> from pyxlsb import open_workbook
>>> wb = open_workbook('readxlsb/test.xlsb')
>>> sheet = wb.get_sheet(1)
>>> [ row for row in sheet.rows()]
[[Cell(r=0, c=0, v='A'), Cell(r=0, c=1, v=1.0), Cell(r=0, c=2, v=4.0)], [Cell(r=1, c=0, v='B'), Cell(r=1, c=1, v=2.0), Cell(r=1, c=2, v=5.0)], [Cell(r=2, c=0, v='C'), Cell(r=2, c=1, v=3.0), Cell(r=2, c=2, v=6.0)]]
```

And it also works in my function app, as the code and figure below.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from pyxlsb import open_workbook

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    with open_workbook('readxlsb/test.xlsb') as wb:
        with wb.get_sheet(1) as sheet:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"{[row for row in sheet]}")
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

---

Update:

I'm afraid that all of nuget packages which can parse `xlsb` file are required the native component of Offical Suits, but you can not install the Offical Suits in Azure Function App. So my suggestion is that try to install [`ironpython`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython/) from Nuget and invoke it from C# with `pyxlsb` to do it.

Also, you can create another Function with HTTP trigger or other service to parse `xlsb` file to response JSON result to your current C# Function.